# Use :root in Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

- I have been working on `Shadow DOM` and then I meet a problem.
- I use the `:root {}` syntax to declare some `CSS variables` . But unfortunately, it does not work.
- Here is my code

- On `1.html`

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Shadow DOM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <square-element></square-element>
    <script src="./1.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- On `1.js`:

  ```
  const htmlCode = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTML Shadow DOM</title>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 24px;
      }

      :root {
        --bg-color: cornflowerblue;
      }

      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
      }

      .square {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 5px solid #000;
        background-color: var(--bg-color);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </body>
  </html>`;

  customElements.define(
  "square-element",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

      shadow.innerHTML = htmlCode;
    }
  });
  ```

- Can I use `CSS :root {}` to decalre some varibales in `Shadow DOM`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- shadowDOM is a **DocumentFragment**
  Unlike IFRAMEs, you can't dump a whole `<html>` construct in there
- `:root` is to be used in **Documents**
- `:host` is used from inside a shadowRoot, to target the **host** element `<square-element>`
- `:host`/`<square-element>` itself is a (inline-block) container element;
  no need to add an extra `<div>` inside as 'container' element

```html
<square-element>1</square-element>
<square-element selected>2</square-element>
<square-element color="purple">3</square-element>

<style>
  :root {
    --border-color: grey;
  }
</style>

<script>
  customElements.define( "square-element", class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = 
        `<style>
          :host {
            --bg-color: ${this.getAttribute("color") || "teal"}; 
            display:inline-block;
            width:  100px; 
            height: 100px;
            border: 5px solid var( --border-color , red  );
            background-color: var( --bg-color     , pink );
            border-radius: var(--radius,20px);
            font:30px Arial;
            text-align:center;
            color:beige;
          }
          :host([selected]) { --bg-color: green }
          :host([color])    { --radius: 50px }
          :host(:hover)     { --border-color: gold; cursor: grab }
        </style><slot></slot>`;
      }
    });
</script>
```